# Two images with the same width and height , first one size is 500KB & second one size is 24MB , Why?

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing, drawing, pixel

I wrote two application first one :
Generate image with random colors using Random Class in C# with range from 0 to 255 ARGB Colors for every pixel , the image size is 3000 x 3000 width and height .
Second Application :
Generate image with the same width and height (3000 x 3000) but using range from 60 to 120 for A , R , G , B of ARGB colors for every pixel ...

First App Generate image with size : 500 KB .
Second App Generate Image With Size : 24 MB .

both of them uses PNG as format of the image and 32 bit color depth .
i can't understand what is the difference between both of image , and why this differ in image size ??
 and what things affect significantly the size of the image ?
...........................................................................................................................
Sorry for my bad english .

this is the first app code :

```
public void GenerateImage2()
    {
        Bitmap Img = new Bitmap(3000, 3000, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        LockBitmap LBM = new LockBitmap(Img);
        LBM.LockBits();
        for (int x = 0; x < 3000; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 3000; y++)
            {
                Random Ran = new Random();
                Color C = Color.FromArgb(Ran.Next(0, 255), Ran.Next(0, 255), Ran.Next(0, 255), Ran.Next(0, 255));
                LBM.SetPixel(x, y, C);
            }
        }
        LBM.UnlockBits();
        Img.Save("redandrandom.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    }
```

second app code :

```
GC.Collect();
                int XDim = 0;
                int YDim = 0;
    int ImageDimentions = 3000;
int ForloopRange = ImageDimentions * ImageDimentions;
                Color CurrentColor = Color.Empty;
                Bitmap Btm = new Bitmap(ImageDimentions, ImageDimentions);
                LockBitmap Img = new LockBitmap(Btm);
                Img.LockBits();
                Random Rand = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < ForloopRange; i++)
                {
                    CurrentColor = Color.FromArgb(Rand.Next(0, 255), Rand.Next(0, 255), Rand.Next(0, 255), Rand.Next(0, 255));
                    Img.SetPixel(XDim, YDim, CurrentColor);
                    YDim += 1;
                    if (YDim == ImageDimentions)
                    {
                        XDim += 1;
                        YDim = 0;
                    }
                    if (XDim == ImageDimentions)
                    {
                        Img.UnlockBits();
                        Btm.Save(SavedFileName + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
                        return;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Show code that saves the images in each application - 24M feels like non-compressed version.

Comment: 3000 x 3000 x 4 = 36 MB, getting a 24 MB file is the expected outcome for an image containing random pixels.  Your first app is probably not using Random properly to get the image compressed that heavily, it is one of the standard bugs.  There's very little point in writing code like this, best to move on.

Comment: Answer updated with code ... !!

Comment: Looping with `y` varying fastest is killing your performance.  In both pieces of code.  You want `for (y ...) for (x ...)` and not `for (x...) for (y...)`.

Comment: what is the difference ??!! the width and height are the same (3000) ... !!!

Comment: @ user3507762: Maybe the pixels should be set along the rows for best performance. This was true in the 90s; today I don't know. Maybe you could measure it and tell us the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a (common) mistake as the instances of Ran are created so fast they don't get different seeds. Take it out of the loop to get real (pseudo-)random numbers!

```
    for (int x = 0; x < 3000; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 3000; y++)
        {
            Random Ran = new Random();
```

Since many or most pixels will be the same in the first case, the image size is a lot smaller.

Comment: thank you @Taw ... now i can understand that the colors is the big thing affect significantly the size of image .... isn't it ?

Comment: Indeed. It should even be visible. The more repetitions the better the compression. Make the all the same color and the file size will be near zero. You can see this when you look at photographs: A lot of sky will make the image smaller and a lot of grass and sand and other tiny details will make it larger. This is true for all compressions be they lossy or lossless.

Comment: +1. @user3507762 - check out [RLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) which will give you good idea on how color differences impact compression. Note that RLE is not what actually used in PNGs, it is just the simplest compression to show the impact of color changes on the size.

Comment: RLE, sigh. You make me feel so young. Or was it old?

Answer (score 0):

`PNG` is compressed format. One of them compressed better than another.

Comment: but it's a very big difference in size !!

Comment: @user3507762 If you have many identical pixels, you will have very high compression factor.

Comment: @user3507762, As mentioned TaW, in your first example on fast machine you will have identical pixels, then the compression level will be very high.